# python2 and python3 multiprocessing.process issue

Tags: python, python-3.x, multithreading, multiprocessing

I'm trying to understand what changed between python2 and python3 in the multiprocessing module.
On python2 running this code works like a charm:

```
def RunPrice(items, price):
    print("There is %s items, price is: %s" % (items, price))

def GetTargetItemsAndPrice(cursor):
    res = cursor.execute("SELECT DISTINCT items, price FROM SELLS")
    threads = []
    for row in res.fetchall():
        p = multiprocessing.Process(target=RunPrice, args=(row[0],row[1]))
        threads.append(p)
        p.start()
    for proc in threads:
        proc.join()
```

Let's say there is 2000 entries to be processed in SELLS. On python2 this script run and exit as expected.
On python3 I get a:

```
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/multiprocessing/popen_fork.py", line 69, in _launch
    child_r, parent_w = os.pipe()
OSError: [Errno 24] Too many open files
```

Any idea what happened between python2 and python3?

Comment: What's the output of `ulimit -a` (on the shell)?

Comment: This script runs on linux only.

Comment: This is likely due to 2 things: 1. multiprocessing in python2 starts processes very differently from how multiprocessing starts processes in python3; and 2. Don't create a `Process` object for every entry. Create a `Pool` and distribute the work.

Comment: core file size          (blocks, -c) 0
data seg size           (kbytes, -d) unlimited
scheduling priority             (-e) 0
file size               (blocks, -f) unlimited
pending signals                 (-i) 47145
max locked memory       (kbytes, -l) 65536
open files                      (-n) 1024
pipe size            (512 bytes, -p) 8
POSIX message queues     (bytes, -q) 819200
stack size              (kbytes, -s) 8192
cpu time               (seconds, -t) unlimited
max user processes              (-u) 47145
file locks                      (-x) unlimited

Comment: @Abdou could you provide an example based on the code I provided?

Comment: The error basically says that your main process is trying to open too many pipes to talk to all the processes you have created. Since `ulimit -n` returns 1024, it looks like you opened too many pipes. Probably 2000 of them.

Comment: @Abdou is there anyways to limit  multiprocessing.process to 1000 pipes until it finishes and then proceed with the remaining ones?

Comment: @n00bz0r Not quite, but using a pool might help a little. [Here is a tweaked version](https://gist.github.com/AbdouSeck/8d70a05891d0c7079126cd9d571f9b01#file-too_many_open_files-py) of your code.

Answer (score 1):

I am assuming that your actual `RunPrice` function is a bit more CPU-intensive than what you show. Otherwise, this would not be a good candidate for multiprocessing. If `RunPrice` were very CPU-intensive and does not relinquish the CPU to wait for I/O to complete, it would not be advantageous to have a processing pool with more processes than the number of CPU cores that you have when you consider that creating processes is not a particularly inexpensive operation (although certainly not as expensive as it would be if you were running on Windows).

```python
from multiprocessing import Pool

def RunPrice(items, price):
    print("There is %s items, price is: %s" % (items, price))

def GetTargetItemsAndPrice(cursor):
    res = cursor.execute("SELECT DISTINCT items, price FROM SELLS")
    rows = res.fetchall()
    MAX_POOL_SIZE = 1024
    # if RunPrice is very CPU-intensive, it may not pay to have a pool size
    # greater than the number of CPU cores you have. In that case:
    #from multiprocessing import cpu_count
    #MAX_POOL_SIZE = cpu_count()
    pool_size = min(MAX_POOL_SIZE, len(rows))
    with Pool(pool_size) as pool:
        # return values from RunPrice:
        results = pool.starmap(RunPrice, [(row[0], row[1]) for row in rows])
```